# Tumblr images resize/crop to fit

Tags: css

I want to make my images on tumblr the same square size 300X300px, yet remain in the same aspect ratio (crop not stretch). When using `max-width` and `max-height` it just stretches them, and when on `auto` it just fits one of the 2 and remains rectangular. Is there a way for it to be resized and cropped to fit the 300x300 square without distortion?

Comment: Do you have the ability to set the images as background images in CSS? Then you could use `background-size:cover;`.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to add css then

```
.image-container-div {
  background-image: url("image-url");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are dealing with dynamic content you are still able to manipulate them through CSS by setting the background image within the HTML like so

CSS:

```
.square-img {
    background: no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

HTML:

```
{block:Photo}
<div class="square-img" style="background-image:url('{PhotoURL-400}')"></div>
{/block:Photo}
```